# verrUsing netdom.exe to "Un"Join a domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain, active-directory

I need to unjoin a computer from the domain preferably form the command line. I know how to use netdom.exe to join a machine to a domain. Is there a corresponding way to un-join it?

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

netdom remove /d:DOMAINNAME, I think.

Comment: +1 - see Example 8 at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776879%28WS.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

netdom remove %computername% /domain:domainname.com